# Error while running "node watch" command from node.js

Tags: node.js, watch

I am trying to run "node watch" command for my project directory from node terminal. It throws error saying "cannot find module "C:\Users......\watch".
I also tried installing it using

```
npm install node-watch.
```

But this does not help as well.

Answer (score 0):

`node-watch` is not something you can run from the terminal. It is a library that will watch for file changes and will trigger a callback when a change is detected.

If you are trying to reload your nodejs program every time you change it, you should try something like `nodemon' . https://github.com/remy/nodemon

To install it: `npm install -g nodemon`

To run your app: `nodemon myprogram.js`